# How does the UE5 Control Rig Sphere Trace by Trace Channel Work?

Tags: animation, raycasting, blueprints, unreal-5

I would like to use a control rig to correct the foot IK.

First, I defined a function called "FootTrace" to detect the ground under the feet. In this function, I used "GetTransform-Bone" to obtain the Transform of the foot bone, but only used its translation vector component.

Then, I used "sphere Trace By Trace Channel" on this vector component, with the starting point being the IK Vector with a Z-axis increase of 50, and the endpoint being the IK Vector with a Z-axis decrease of 100. I tested the Hit Location of this "sphere Trace By Trace Channel" and found that it returns the distance from the foot (or heel component) to the ground.

[image: Graph showing 5 added to y component of translation, and 50 to z]
[image: Graph showing 100 subtracted from z component, feeding into Sphere Trace]

Then I tried replacing the vector with the head or hands, but the Hit Location of the sphere Trace By Trace Channel remained unchanged. Is this a bug in my UE5 or something else?"

[image: Graph showing hand and foot wiring]
[image: Screenshot showing debug prints]

No matter what method I use, even when customizing a coordinate from top to bottom for the sphere Trace By Trace Channel, the result still returns a distance from somewhere to the ground